# How to join tables (from one-to-many to one-to-one) based on proportion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have two tables:

```
|Order|Produce|       |Produce|Type |Proportion|
|  1  |Apple  |       |Apple  |Red  |0.67      |
|  2  |Orange |       |Apple  |Green|0.33      |
|  3  |Apple  |       |Orange |Sweet|1.0       |
|  4  |Apple  |
|  5  |Orange |
```

I would like to assign type (from the right table) on the produce based on the proportion (it can be random).

As an example because there are:

- 3 apple orders
- 2 apple types (red - 67% and green - 33%)

Two of the apple orders will be allocated red and one order to be allocated green:

```
|Order|Produce|Type |
|  1  |Apple  |Red  |
|  2  |Orange |Sweet|
|  3  |Apple  |Green|
|  4  |Apple  |Red  |
|  5  |Orange |Sweet|
```

I understand the calculation will not always be precise and neat so if the allocation is a bit off because of sample size that's fine.

I've been trying to come up with some logic using SQL window function (sorting based on row number and groups) but couldn't get the results I want.

I've also tried using the data merge in SAS but can't get the random allocation going.

Any ideas/suggestion on the way/logic to do this?

Comment: Please post your query - even if its not producing the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would enumerate the rows and do simple calculation:

```
select o.*, t.type
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by produce order by newid()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by produce) as cnt
      from orders o
     ) o join
     (select t.*,
             sum(proportion) over (partition by produce order by proportion) - proportion as lower,
             sum(proportion) over (partition by produce order by proportion) as upper
      from types t
     ) t
     on o.produce = t.produce and
        (seqnum - 1) * 1.0 / cnt >= lower and
        (seqnum - 1) * 1.0 / cnt < upper;
```

The key here is calculating the upper and lower bounds using a cumulative sum of the proportion.  Then using this to compare to the enumeration divided by the count.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=930cdbe7b83bdd28497def2c8e7e5163) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks the logic works like a charm! Really appreciate it!